# Power Apps Integration with Evernote

Tags: c#, powerapps, power-automate, evernote, power-platform

this body includes three parts please read them all:

1. I have a client who wants to integrate power apps with Evernote to edit and show notes using this app, I have tried a lot but I can't figure out how to do this, I read an article and it tells that I need to download a CData server...
   also, I request Evernote to get their API and it includes that I need to install SDK which suits my platform so, it means that I have to work with visual studio using C# to add this SDK on it than working with power apps.
2. I have integrated Evernote with Microsoft Teams and it works, so could I get access to Evernote using Microsoft teams connector on power apps?
3. I tried HTTP requests from power automate, but also I struggle with API

what should I do?

Comment: The best way is a hard way. Learn the API so you can have a better solution.  If you can't code with the API, use the Teams connector.

Comment: @osfresia can I get access on Evernote after adding it on teams? I integrated them together(Evernote and Teams), and now I'm discovering teams connector functions to know how to get access to Evernote using it, but I can't find a resource that includes this problem (get access to an app that added on Teams)

Comment: Yes you can, the app on Teams can _Capture, organize, and share notes_.

Comment: @osfresia I apologize for my many questions, but I did that on Microsoft Teams itself when I added Evernote on it, I edited and added notes on Evernote using it.
My question is, How could I use the Microsoft Teams Connector on POWERAPPS so I can display Evernote App on Power Apps to edit and add Notes on it?

Comment: Look at using the API's ... https://dev.evernote.com/doc/